# In local machine, django project run on which server?

Tags: django

i have only query to in which server python run and django run
please help , on which server Django run locally?
gunicorn and uwsgi is same?

Comment: I think he run on wsgi, because once I had do install gunicorn to deploy my server

Comment: Djnago server its running on wsgi server

Answer (score 0):

When you run `django-admin runserver [addrport]`, it is started a lightweight development Web server on the local machine. The server uses the WSGI application object specified by the WSGI_APPLICATION setting. In production you can use different servers (don’t use the default server).